# Are there any other ways to run two different loops in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two loops, i loop I am counting rows in the first sheet, ii loops counting rows in the second sheet, but in my second sheet, my condition doesn't meet the requirement I need, it just goes back to i loop.  I am want to find an empty cell in the second loop, but it doesn't go through the whole condition. Any Idea...

```
For i = 3 To lastrow
 ' condition to check number
 If IsNumeric(ws1.Cells(i, 1)) Then
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
    cName = ws1.Cells(i, 1)
    'This one is for second loop
      For ii = 3 To lastroww
           If ws2.Cells(ii, 3) = "" Then
            ws2.Cells(ii, 3) = "Name" + cName + "City"
           End If
      Next ii
  End If
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: What is the exact problem? I only found an error in how you concatenate your value. Should be: "Name " & cName & " City"

Comment: is this a typo `lastroww`?

Comment: After your inner loop is first executed, its If condition will never be met again as no cells will be empty. Is that really what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

the initial loop for i goes through the all the values in the first sheet one by one, and for every value, in sheet one we go through all the values in the sheet two as this loop is nested with the first loop. ie

```
For i = 3 To lastrow

  For ii = 3 To lastroww
      ' for every i you go through all values in sheet 2
  Next ii
```

End If
  End If
Next i

so if you have 10 elements in sheet one and 10 elements in sheet 2 . you outer loop selects the first element in sheet 1 and then checks all the 10 elements in sheet 2. net it picks second element in sheet 1 and again goes through the same 10 elements in sheet 2 and continues.

so when your outer loop for i runs initially it fills the values in the second sheet which were missing. now as these values are filled ,for next i values the condition for null value in second sheet are not met as they have been filled in the first iteration.

I hope it clarifies your query.

Comment: My code doesn't go through the whole rows, it just go to the first row I mean the 4th row and goes back to loop i. Row 4 is not an empty row, so It is not going through every rows.

Comment: if you could share your sheet it would make more sense to go through the code.

Comment: It's working basically I had to add lastroww inside the For loop

Answer (score 0):

```
   For ii = 3 To lastroww
        lastroww = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
          If ws2.Cells(ii, 3) = "" Then
          ws2.Cells(ii, 3) = "Name" + cName + "City"
       End If
  Next ii
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the logic of your solution?